# Rails merge similar params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/recipes?search=items&item_id[]=1805&item_id[]=1808
```

This URL appeared from

```
<%= form_tag(recipes_path, method: "get", :enforce_utf8 => false) do %>
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="items">
<%= select_tag "item_id", options_for_select(["155", "156", "157", "158"]), multiple: true, class: 'chosen-select', id: 'unique_id', data: { placeholder: "Enter the ids" } %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

How can I merge identical URL params to let them look like the following, and also remove square brackets?

```
http://localhost/recipes?search=items&item_id=1805,1808
```

Comment: “I have an URL like this”—where this URL appeared from?

Comment: added code to post

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to shrink the URL or just get the params together? because with your URL  you can already access the array with `params["item_id"]`.

From what I see in your URL example, `params["item_id"][0]` will be `1805` and `params["item_id"][1]` will be `1808`.

Comment: just want to shrink the url to look like this
http://localhost/recipes?search=items&item_id=1805,1808